# OpenSSH: allow nonexistent user to login

Tags: ssh, login, openssh, pam

I'm trying to login using SSH on a OpenSSH Linux server with nonexistent unix logins that will be authenticated through to a external webservice using PAM module pam_exec and create a local account on first login.

When the login does not existent, OpenSSH send a fake password to pam_exec that fail authenticate on the webservice.

How can I pass the real password to pam_exec even with the login does not exist?

Comment: I have exact problem, I got a `Invalid user test from 192.168.x.x port 39354` log and find out that sshd tries to get user data through `getpwnam` before even pam requests sent.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: You'll need to make OpenSSH think the user *does* exist. On Linux with glibc, you could write a custom nsswitch module that always returns *some* information for any username (possibly checking whether sshd is the caller), similar to the existing modules libnss_ldap, libnss_systemd, libnss_cache, and so on. The nsswitch module doesn't need to "create" the account, only report a valid UID for it.

Option 2: Patch sshd to not send a fake password.

Comment: I already created a pam_exec module that authenticate against the webservice and create the user account when it runs locally, but fails when the login is through SSH. I read somewhere that OpenSSH needs to find the local user to get the UID, GID, and the user shell. If I create the NSS module, does OpenSSH could do it right with the fake user information?

Comment: Yes, that was the point of the post.